# Javascript FileReader in a storing to memory - parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, filereader

ok so I have read a number of articles and tried a number of approaches. Neither of them work.I am trying to build the File Reader into my code and I just get error after error, over and over again. Note: This is a reduced version of the code. I have also tried about 10 different ways, neither successful, hence the question.

```
function init(){
    // start the constructor
    constructTable = new constructTableS("ConstructionTable");
};

function constructTableS(name){
    // Variables 
    this.name = name;
    this.csv = "";
}

constructTableS.prototype.load = function(files){
    if (window.FileReader) {
        // FileReader is supported.
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e){
            //Tried this as well : var csv = event.target.result}; 
            this.csv = reader.result};

        var x = reader.readAsText(files);



    } else {
        alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
    };
```

The aim is to begin the function with the body initialization.

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Then call the load function of the "class" and send it the data from the file?

```
<input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="constructTable.load(this.files)" accept=".csv">
```

The error that I get is: **parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.** This comes from this line **var x = reader.readAsText(files);**

what I'm trying to do is load the data into a variable not an innerHTML slot. I've read numerous examples such as these. [parameter is not of type 'Blob'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923985/parameter-is-not-of-type-blob)

As soon as the event is called, it either won't recognize my class and ignore any functions in the class, thus I can't store the data. Or it just returns, not of type blob.

I have taken the example from here:
http://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2012/11/20/reading-csv-file-with-javascript-and-html5-file-api/

That works but it it doesn't read the code into a variable in a class that I can call when I need it.

Comment: One reader can only read a single file. Use a loop over `files`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="constructTable.load(this.files)" accept=".csv">` The `this.files` returns an array of uploaded files, to read one file at a time, use a loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //your logic goes here
}
```

The `this` refers to the current `HTMLElement` which is the file input element and this element has a property called `files` which is an array of files that were selected.

Or if you only allow users to upload one file at a time, change `this.files` to `this.files[0]`

Comment: Yeah Thanks I get that, but it doesn't solve the error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: did you change the `this.files` to `this.files[0]` ? Because the error indicates that you are passing it the right type which is of type `Blob` or `File` which is a subtype of `Blob`, break on the line that is causing the error and use the debugger to see what type the passed argument is.

Comment: Ok it was the files[0]. I see the issue. I'm still not managing to extract the data out of the Filereader loop? Running this command **this.csv = reader.result};** the this in this case is the Filereader which is not helpful for me.